# Flutter Pub.dev create publisher not working

Tags: flutter, dart, publish, google-search-console

I am trying to link a publisher to my profile but can not make it work. I have a website [`https://christiankonnerth.me`](https://christiankonnerth.me).

*Steps:*

1. Go to pub.dev and create publisher
2. insert *christiankonnerth.me* as `publisher domain`
3. Get error

[image]

4. Go to *Google Search Console*
5. succesfull verification

[image]

6. back to pub.dev to get the same error from *3*

I couldn't find anything on this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was signed into another Google Account then on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) . After signing into the same account I was able to add the DNS record and create a publisher.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, by searching my domain from here
https://search.google.com/search-console/about
and verified the association.

then, try again to create my pub.dev publisher, and I succeeded created it.